# at compile time, how JVM can find unnecessary catching of CloneNotSupportedException but not Exception?

Tags: java, exception

```
public class MyClass {
  public static void method() {
    try {
    // there is no compile time error for unnecessary catching 'Exception'
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      // why compile time error for unnecessary catching 'MyException' or
      // 'CloneNotSupportedException' etc..
      // ultimately Exception, MyException &  CloneNotSupportedException all 
      // are checked exception
      

    } catch (MyException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
class MyException extends Exception {
}

second scenario
---------------
public class MyClass {
    public static void method() throws Exception {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // if Exception itself is not checked ,
        // why compile time error occured for calling method(); ??
        method();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because RuntimeExceptions are subclasses of Exception class. Therefore, compiler can't determine if some code throws any runtime exception, as they might be thrown by jvm. 
On the other hand - checked exceptions must be declared that are thrown by some method, so the compiler knows which exceptions could be thrown and can determine unnecessary catch blocks.

Comment: Thanks for reply,
but if Exception itself is unchecked exception then why we need to handle/catch it ? see the second scenario.

Comment: Because an Exception could be a checked exception.

Comment: so the conclusion is like, 'Exception' class behavior is like mixing of both Checked & Unchecked exception:
1) Checked Behavior : if its used with 'throws' clause, the callee function must catch or forward it
2) Unchecked Behavior : unnecessary try-catch block with 'Exception'  allowed by JVM.  Right ??

Answer (score 1):

Methods declare what exceptions they throw. If you're catching anything that is not a superclass of any known exception types then the catching isn't necessary.

Answer (score 0):

We have *checked* exceptions and *unchecked* Exceptions. `CloneNotSupportedException` is a checked exception: if a methods *throws* it, the caller needs to *catch* this type of exception. And in those cases, the jvm can detect, if it is catched while no method inside the try block ever throws it.

`Exception` itself is not checked.

Comment: if exception itself is not checked then why below code throws compile time error:
public class MyClass {
 public static void method() throws Exception {
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  method();
 }
}